# Flow or Visualforce page: what could be a best practice?

Tags: apex, flow

I've recently made some tests about Visual Workflow and Flow Cloud Designer, for flows creation. Now I'm wondering about a "philosophical" doubt, that is : for example, I'd like to have a custom button on a standard obj's detail page that performs some operations and return the same detail page (for example, a button on opportunity record detail page that create an order based on opportunity products).
So,  I could reach my goal by calling Apex from a VF page related to the button. But also, I could create a flow that makes the same operation . Now, which of the 2 options would you choose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question highly depends on the context (what level of customization is needed? how fast do you want it done? Who will have to maintain it?)

However consider the following:

**flow pros**

- very easy to build and maintain, given that you need not too complex operations
- processes easily explained to the business
- works as a charm combined with Processes, easily replacing trigger necessity
- faster than developing code
- no need for developers
- still able to use apex by plugins or apex calls (the latter available from Spring '15

**flow cons**

- very limited debugging options. When facing more complex operations it can be a pain to find issues
- obviously not as flexible as code.
- limited styling options.

Hope this helps you!